# How to create complicated function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have Python Data Frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"code" : [1,1,2,2,3], "value" : [10, 11, 11, 11, 30]})
```

Next, I found combinations code x value without duble

```
cc = df.groupby(['code','value']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
cc
```

Next, I need to create function where each combination of code x value from cc will be used, and then saved in Data Frame, for example

[image]

for index 0 is code = 1 and value = 10 and I need to function which will iterate for combination code x value for each index and will summarize these value, for example:

for index 0 -> 1+10 = 11

for index 1 - > 1+11 = 12

for index 2 ->2+11 = 13

for index 3 -> 3 +30 = 33

And return results of function in Data Frame like below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not following. Maybe this: df['res'] = df['code'] + df['value']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very simple function...  whatever function you want in apply

```
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({"code" : [1,1,2,2,3], "value" : [10, 11, 11, 11, 30]})
cc = df.groupby(['code','value']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
cc = cc.assign(result=cc.apply(lambda r: math.sqrt(r.code**2 + r.value**3), axis=1)).rename(columns={"code":"col1","value":"col2"}).drop(columns="count")
```

Comment: OK but I need to create function not use existing function, I simply need to use combination of code value for each index in DF